C# Exception Messages & Performance: is the exception message string created even if the exception is not thrown?
This might smell like micro-optimization - but in this case, I'm running a loop tens of millions of times and performance is critical (and a significant issue at the moment).
In this scenario, during each iteration of the loop, I'm doing a check like this:
   if (this.isSafeMode && bar.Period != this.SourcePeriod)
   {
       throw new InvalidOperationException(
           "Attempted to process a bar that does not match the market context's source period. " +
           $"Processed bar period: [{bar.Period}] " +
           $"Market context source period: [{this.SourcePeriod}]");
   }

Question 1: Is this exception message string created on every loop even if the exception isn't thrown, creating unnecessary overhead? (In other cases, I have rather expensive exception strings to build - this is a simple example)
Question 2: If Question #1 is true, would creating a custom exception type that accepts arguments and builds the message string from those arguments avoid the unnecessary overhead? (Or, what's an alternative?)
FYI: This exception won't need to be translated into different languages (if that were the case, a custom exception might make more sense).
Thank you for your time!

Question #1 is no

If the if block isn't entered, the string is not created, and separately the exception is not created, and again separately: the exception is not thrown. So: you're fine.

Awesome, thanks Marc!
